# ClickHouse Date + Time

Tags: clickhouse

I am experiencing difficulty in combining a Date and a Time into a single DateTime in ClickHouse.

In SQL Server, I have a view that performs operations like the following:

```
CAST(Date AS DATETIME) + CAST(StartTime AS DATETIME)
```

The values of these two fields are:

Date: 2018-12-31 (Date)
StartTime: 10:59:33 (Time)
The result is: 2018-12-31 10:59:33.000

How can I achieve this same operation in ClickHouse?

I am expecting to execute this operation of date with time to be able to generate a new datetime (2018-12-31 10:59:33.000)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think "10:59:33" all by itself (with no day) makes sense in ClickHouse. But...you could do something like this if both values are strings:

```
WITH
    '10:59:33' AS time,
    '2018-12-31' AS day
SELECT toDateTime64(concat(day, ' ', time), 3)


┌─toDateTime64(concat(day, ' ', time), 3)─┐
│                 2018-12-31 10:59:33.000 │
└─────────────────────────────────────────┘
```